# My code in C for the UNION of two sets is not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the union and intersection of two sets of numbers. The sets can be represented using arrays
So my code is working perfectly for the intersection, but for the union, it does something really weird.

The code should do this:

```
Enter number of elements in set A: 5
Enter set A: 0 4 2 1 6
Enter number of elements in set B: 3
Enter set B: 1 9 3
Union: 0 1 2 3 4 6 9
Intersection: 1
```

My errors for the union are that they are not arranged in order and also it shouldn't print the repeated numbers and it does.

I like don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. Its definitely something wrong with the logic of the union function but idk

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void print_array(int[], int);
    void compute_union(int[], int[], int, int[]);
    void compute_intersection(int, int[], int[], int[]);
    int size1, size2;
    int union_size=0;

    int main()
    {

    printf("Enter the size of your first array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size1);
    printf("Enter the size of your second array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size2);
    printf("Enter the values of your array: ");

    int i,j;
    int arr1[size1];
    int arr2[size2];
    int set_union[size1+size2];
    int set_intersection[(size1+size2)/2];


    for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);

    }

        for(j=0; j<size2; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr2[j]);
    }

    //print_array(arr1,size1);
    compute_union(arr1, arr2, size1+size2, set_union);

    //print_array(set_union, size1+size2);
    compute_intersection((size1+size2)/2, arr1, arr2, set_intersection);

    //print_array(set_intersection, (size1+size2)/2);

    return 0;
    }


    void print_array(int array[], int size)
    {
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<size; x++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[x]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    }

    void compute_union(int s1[], int s2[], int max_size, int set_union[]){

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    while(i<size1 && j<size2)
    {
    if(s1[i]<s2[j])
    {
    set_union[i+j]=s1[i];
    i++;
    }
    else if (s1[i]>s2[j])
    {
    set_union[i+j]=s2[j];
    j++;
    }
    else
   {
    set_union[i+j]=s1[i];
    i++;
    j++;
   }
    }
    //add remainder of nonempty array

    while(i<size1)
    {
    set_union[i+j]=s1[i];
    i++;
    }
    while(j<size2)
    {
    set_union[i+j]=s2[j];
    j++;
    }

    print_array(set_union, size1+size2);
    }

    void compute_intersection(int max_size, int set1[], int set2[], int 
    set_intersection[])
    {
    int i, j, n=0;
    for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
      for(j=0; j<size2; j++)
      {
          if(set1[i]==set2[j])
          {
              set_intersection[k]=set1[i];
              n++;
              break;
          }
      }
    }

    print_array(set_intersection, n);
    }
```

Comment: step through in debugger

Comment: what do you mean? I'm a beginner in C

Comment: what did you find when you typed "C step through in debugger" into a search engine?

Comment: what platform / toolchain are you using? linux / gcc/gdb , windows visual studio,...

Comment: I'm using windows with a  GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: If the arrays aren't in order, why do you think a linear search/merge will necessarily find the duplicates?  And if there are duplicates, shouldn't the size of `set_union` be smaller than the sum of the sizes of A and B?

Comment: Yes, you are right @ScottHunter, but I believe it shouldn't affect that much. It will be slightly smaller than the sizes

Comment: The variable `k` in `compute_intersection` is not declared.

Answer (score 3):

You never sort your arrays, but it looks like the `compute_union()` routine is assuming sorted arrays.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Why should it be a comment?  I believe I've identified his problem.  Talk about contributing to people feeling unwelcome .....

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this answers the question, and actually answers should not be posted in comments

Comment: @M.M Not really.  The fundamental definiton of a set is that it does not contain duplicates.  This answer doesn't address this problem at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean, it attempts to answer the question. Wrong answers don't go in comments either!   But if the input is sorted then the existing algorithm will produce sorted outputs without duplicates, so the implied suggestion of providing sorted input is in fact a correct answer

Answer (score 2):

> My errors for the union are that they are not arranged in order and also it shouldnt print the repeated numbers and it does.

Sets typically are not ordered data structures, unless you specifically need an ordered set.  But the second requirement about non repeated numbers is valid for a set; a set should not contain duplicates.  One approach here would be to simply iterate the `set_union` array and check if a value exists before adding it.  Only new values would be added, something like this:

```
int compute_union(int s1[], int s2[], int max_size, int set_union[]) {

    int num_elements = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < size1; ++i) {
        int present = 0;
        for (int n=0; n < num_elements; ++n) {
            if (set_union[n] == s1[i]) {
                present = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (present == 0) {
            set_union[num_elements] = s1[i];
            ++num_elements;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < size2; ++i) {
        int present = 0;
        for (int n=0; n < num_elements; ++n) {
            if (set_union[n] == s2[i]) {
                present = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (present == 0) {
            set_union[num_elements] = s2[i];
            ++num_elements;
        }
    }

    // return the size of the actual set
    return num_elements;
}
```

This isn't a very efficient way of implementing a set.  One typical way a set is implemented is using a hash map.  In this case, we can lookup to see if a value is contained within the set in constant time.  The above approach means we have to potentially scan the entire array "set" to check for a value.

Comment: I tried this, it's still not working. I used the same example mentioned above and this is what it outputs for the union: 0 4 2 1 6 9 3 4199538

Comment: at least know is not repeating values, but it's still printing garbage

Comment: It looks like you are iterating past the size of the array.  I updated my answer to return the number of elements in the `set_union` set array.  Only iterate this far, and you won't print garbage.

Comment: So when I return the num_elements I get the same output. Should I delete the declaration of the size of union (which was the sum of size 1 and size 2)

Comment: You are iterating one time too many.  _Don't_ access `set_union[num_elements]`, don't go higher than `num_elements - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking if an element is already stored in the union set array or not.

If you don't want to sort the arrays first, you could use a function like

```
int srch(int *a, int size, int x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            return 1;   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to perform linear search. `srch()` will return `1` for successful search and `0` otherwise.

Modify the `compute_union()` function to

```
int compute_union(int s1[], int s2[], int max_size, int set_union[]){
    int i=0;
    int cursize=0;
    for(i=0; i<size1; ++i)
    {
        if(srch(set_union, cursize, s1[i])==0)
        {
            set_union[cursize++] = s1[i];
        }
    }   
    for(i=0; i<size2; ++i)
    {
        if(srch(set_union, cursize, s2[i])==0)
        {
            set_union[cursize++] = s2[i];
        }
    }   
    return cursize;
}
```

and `compute_intersection()` to

```
int compute_intersection(int max_size, int set1[], int set2[], int set_intersection[])
{
    int i, j, cursize=0;
    for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<size2; j++)
        {
          if(set1[i]==set2[j])
          {
              set_intersection[cursize++]=set1[i];
              break;
          }
        }
    }
    return cursize;
}
```

These 2 functions will return the size of the union and intersection sets respectively.

Let the size be stored in variables `usize` and `nsize`.

```
usize = compute_union(arr1, arr2, size1+size2, set_union);
print_array(set_union, usize);

nsize = compute_intersection((size1+size2)/2, arr1, arr2, set_intersection);
print_array(set_intersection, nsize);
```

For the inputs in the question, output will be

```
Union: 0 4 2 1 6 9 3
Intersection: 1
```

Better way would be to sort the elements of the input arrays and then examining them though.